# NSString: split string by given character or substring

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a string structured in this way:

`"Description#Data#IMG"`

What's the best method to obtain three distinct strings through the position of sharps?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
NSString *str=@"Description#Data#IMG";  //is your str

NSArray *items = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];   //take the one array for split the string

NSString *str1=[items objectAtIndex:0];   //shows Description
NSString *str2=[items objectAtIndex:1];   //Shows Data
NSString *str3=[items objectAtIndex:2];   // shows IMG

Finally NSLog(@"your  3 stirs ==%@   %@  %@", str1, str2, str3);
```

**Swift**

```
 //is your str  
 var str: String = "Description#Data#IMG"

let items = String.components(separatedBy: "#") //take the one array for split the string
var str1: String = items.objectAtIndex(0)    //shows Description
var str2: String = items.objectAtIndex(1)    //Shows Data
var str3: String = items.objectAtIndex(2) // shows IMG
```

**option-2**

```
let items = str.characters.split("#")
var str1: String  =  String(items.first!)
var str1: String  =  String(items.last!)
```

**option 3**

```
// An example string separated by commas.
let line = "apple,peach,kiwi"

// Use components() to split the string.
// ... Split on comma chars.
let parts = line.components(separatedBy: ",")

// Result has 3 strings.
print(parts.count)
print(parts)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSArray *components=[@"Description#Data#IMG" componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
NSString *string = @"Description#Data#IMG";

NSArray *items = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
```